# Make content inside fixed sidebar scrollable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I made this js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VaCfV/3/

It has some long content and a fixed positioned sidebar with content inside it. I'm trying to figure out how to make content inside sidebar `#side-content` scrollable Not by using `overflow-y: scrollable;` but actually scroll together with page when user uses mouse wheel, arrow keys, main scrollbar etc..

Can this be somehow achieved?

Comment: That's not the concept of a "fixed" element. Maybe you need to re-think if you really want a fixed element.

Comment: @Steve I understand, but the thing is if it is not fixed the white part sidebar will eventually "finish", in fact sidebar will finish and there will be just grey space instead of sidebar, but for my design idea I need to keep it white all the way.

Comment: That's a very common problem. Try to solve it it using a background for the whole page or something similar. Your solution doesn't make sense for me.

Comment: @Steve Alright, I really don't wan't to use background for this, I guess I'll wait to see if someone else comes up with an idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try:

```
#page-wrapper{
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
#sidebar {
    width: 30%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 20px;
    top:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    background: #fff;
    border-left: 1px solid #000;
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VaCfV/4/

Comment: YES! does what I initially intended.